# MVC 3 App Dashboard slow loading, multiple queries (AutoMapper, EF, Kendo UI)

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3, automapper, repository-pattern

Let me try this again...

MVC 3
Repository Pattern
Automapper for ViewModels

I put my app onto my server and when loading the dashboard (which in turn loads 5 Kendo UI charts) it bogs the server down and the processor peaks out at 100%. IT takes anywhere from 5-10 seconds to load the page.

I am trying to optimize with EF Profiler. I noticed that all kinds of queries are made, which makes sense when you see my dashboard controller. But AutoMapper seems to take a long time converting over 1800 records to the viewmodel. Can I cache my repo for use across the controllers or something?

```
Public Class DashboardController
    Inherits BaseController

    Private ticketRepo As MaintenanceTicketsRepository

    Public Sub New()
        Me.ticketRepo = New MaintenanceTicketsRepository(New TicketContext)
    End Sub

    Function Chart_OpenItemsByPM() As ActionResult
        Dim tickets = ticketRepo.GetAll().Include(Function(p) p.Priority).Include(Function(s) s.Status).OrderBy(Function(o) o.PriorityId).ToArray()

        Mapper.CreateMap(Of MaintenanceTicket, PieChartViewModel)()

        Dim queue As PieChartViewModel() = Mapper.Map(Of MaintenanceTicket(), PieChartViewModel())(tickets)

        Dim ticketCounts = From t In queue _
                           Where t.StatusName = "Open" And _
                           t.PriorityName <> "Not Ready" _
                           Group t By t.PriorityName Into Count() _
                           Select PriorityName, Id = Count

        Return Json(ticketCounts)
    End Function
```

**UPDATE:**
If anyone does reads this, I also wonder about the filling the "tickets" object. I fill this in each of my functions as they are called via ajax. Which means I am sending multiple queries for the same set of initial data that I later slim down in the function.

Is there a pattern for filling a repository ONCE and then reusing it?

Comment: You should only doing the mapping configuration (`Mapper.CreateMap`) once, but I'm not sure how much of a performance overhead this would cause. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13867664/1505426) for a way to configure it. Caching would have to be done manually by you - I use [ServiceStack Caching](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Caching) for this in my app.

Comment: Thank you, I had wondered that and I have started already to put the configuration into a bootstrapper class and set that up in my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using stored procedures that do the calculations and then just load by the necessary (a ton less) rows. Didnt feel ideal, but as another poster said, let the tools do what they are best at, and sql is best at data aggregation in this situation.